# Suggested design pattern for email templates?

Tags: .net, design-patterns

From the "It must have been done 1 million times before" department...I need to integrate a email templating solution into an existing .Net product.  Right now, each component (workflow, admin, etc) sends out their own hard-coded emails.  I would like to introduce a new admin site/screen that allows users to pick from a set of email templates.  The templates themselves will be fairly simplistic, with some string substitution based on business rules.

Question is: is there a design pattern that covers the creation and usage of email templates?  Examples? I have started to look at Strategy and the Template Design Pattern.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it simple and use existing technologies as much as possible, I would suggest implement it using XSL templates (to generate e-mail body in HTML or plain-text format).

I will also suggest looking at [system.web.ui.webcontrols.maildefinition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.maildefinition.aspx)

You can find some ready templates on the market ([templateengine.net](http://www.xtremeui.com/templateengine.net.aspx)) and also SSRS can be used as e-mail generator, but this will be probably an overkill.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a design pattern, at least not the one in the "Strategy" or "Template Method" category. The closest thing I would say this comes to is the [Builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern), but I guess it would be an overkill unless your business rules are complex.

As for the templating itself, I suggest you take a look at [NVelocity](http://www.castleproject.org/others/nvelocity/index.html).

Comment: Personally, I don't recommend NVelocity. It's an awful port. More details over at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/346449/templating-engine-to-generate-simple-reports-in-net