# ASP.NET MVC Templating

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have repetitious markup for elements, like:

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="content">
      content goes here
    </div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Top and bottom are styled with css to include images for borders.

I could use JQuery to inject tags, but is there a better way to template controls in asp.net mvc?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probably a lot of ways around this, here's one:

Create a ViewUserControl (let's call it "box.ascx"):

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<Action>" %>
<div class="box">
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="content">
        <% Model(); %>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

In your aspx, wherever you need this block, call it like this:

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("box", Lambda.Action(() => { %>
here comes my content! <a href="http://www.google.com">Google!</a>
<% })); %>
```

Here's the Lambda helper class:

```
public static class Lambda {
    public static Action Action(Action a) {
        return a;
    }
}
```

If you don't use this little helper it will crash since it will try to cast the Action.

Answer (score 1):

I just defined two extension methods to write the tags

```
  public static void BeginBox(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
  {
      StringBuilder box = new StringBuilder();

      box.AppendLine("<div class=\"box\">");
      box.AppendLine("    <div class=\"top\"></div>");
      box.AppendLine("        <div class=\"content\">");

      htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Response.Write(box.ToString());
  }

  public static void EndBox(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
  {
      StringBuilder box = new StringBuilder();

      box.AppendLine("        </div>");
      box.AppendLine("    <div class=\"bottom\"></div>");
      box.AppendLine("</div>");

      htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Response.Write(box.ToString());
  }
```

I guess this will do for now.

Comment: why not have the methods return the html in a string?

Answer (score 1):

You definitely want to use an extension method to the HtmlHelper so that you can then use the notation:

```
<%=Html.Box("content string") %>
```

---

```
public static stringBox(
       this HtmlHelper html, 
       string Content)
  {
      var sb = new StringBuilder();

      sb.AppendLine("<div class=\"box\">");
      sb.AppendLine("    <div class=\"top\"></div>");
      sb.AppendLine("        <div class=\"content\">");
      sb.AppendLine(Content);
      sb.AppendLine("        </div>");
      sb.AppendLine("    <div class=\"bottom\"></div>");
      sb.AppendLine("</div>");

      return sb.ToString();
  }
```

Comment: This would get quite ugly if the "content string" is actually html instead of just text, or if I wanted to include calls to Html.TextBox() and such.

Comment: True but you can use the other extension methods (beginBox and endBox) shown blu's answer for that circumstance.

Comment: If you code both solutions then you'd have the markup duplicated... it would be in blu's extensions and then again in your extension.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no Built-In templating solution in asp.net mvc. But because the output is pure html it is very easy to do your own templating with just css and maybe a bit of JS.

Of course since everything in asp.net mvc is swappable you can replace the default view engine with one that supports templating.

Comment: Am I thinking more along the lines of a Server Controls for mvc

Comment: View engines are really template engines. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/340095/

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use master pages? You can use master pages in MVC just like in ASP.Net