# .net Email Template engine

Tags: c#, templates, email-templates

I'm looking to create emails, mainly HTML, based on templates -
I'd really like to do something like:

1. Set up my template, as an HTML (or
   similar) file
2. Include tags, that are then replaced with specific data (kind of like mail-merge....)

I've seen this:
http://www.bitethebullet.co.uk/EmailTemplateFramework/tabid/58/Default.aspx

From searching on stack overflow, i understand nVelocity might be another option? But i can't find any examples to do what i want to do...

Any other suggestions?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/340095/can-you-recommend-a-net-template-engine

Comment: Slightly different questions - this one is asking for a templating engine that specialises in email, the other for generic engines that can also handle email.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This kind of functionality is already built in. See [MailDefinition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.maildefinition.aspx) class. For more complex scenarios you might want to consider something like NVelocity. I've had a lot of success with [StringTemplate's C# port](http://www.stringtemplate.org/).

Answer (score 3):

I've just released an open source project for precisely this purpose. You can read some more details and grab the source code from my blog.

http://thecodedecanter.wordpress.com/2010/07/19/town-crier-an-open-source-e-mail-templating-engine-for-net/