# Custom Tag in HTMl

Tags: c#, asp.net-3.5

I want a shopify like functionality in my app which I am developing. Shopify template engine support this syntax in theme files.

```
<ul id="blogs">
  {% for article in blogs.frontpage.articles limit: 3 %}
  <li><a href="{{ article.url }}">{{ article.title }}</a></li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

I also want this type of functionality for mine.

Comment: Most environments with viewengines have a plugin model, the question is, why do you need your own viewengine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need a templating engine for your app. You could use an off the shelf one such as the ones recommnded [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/340095/can-you-recommend-a-net-template-engine).

Comment: Looking at it, let see I get what I need. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your example code looks exactly like a [Django template](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/templates/): if that's precisely what you want, you can use Django templates in .NET with [IronPython](http://ironpython.net/) (if you don't care about the kind of template language in use, @mopoke's answer gives a URL listing many others).

Comment: I dont want to use Django templates. But its a good suggestion. Thanks