# HTML Templating engine to be used inside SQL Server?

Tags: html, sql-server-2008-r2, .net-assembly, template-engine, sqlclr

Are there any good .NET templating engines which can be used in standalone mode, and can be loaded into SQL Server as a managed assembly?

Answer (score 1):

I would reccomend Brail. Brail can be used in standalone mode and it can be loaded into a SQL Server as a managed assembly. [Brail](http://docs.castleproject.org/MonoRail.Brail.ashx). Also there was a similar question asked [Question Asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/340095/can-you-recommend-a-net-template-engine)

Comment: Did this help at all?