# Extracts all sub strings between string separators in a string (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, string, parsing

I'm trying to parse content of a string to see if the string includes urls, to convert the full string to html, to make the string clickable.

I'm not sure if there is a smarter way of doing this, but I started trying creating a parser with the Split method for strings, or Regex.Split in C#. But I can't find a good way of doing it.

(It is a ASP.NET MVC application, so perhaps there is some smarter way of doing this)

I want to ex. convert the string;

```
"Customer office is responsible for this. Contact info can be found {link}{www.customerservice.com}{here!}{link} More info can be found {link}{www.customerservice.com/moreinfo}{here!}{link}"
```

Into

```
"Customer office is responsible for this. Contact info can be found <a href=www.customerservice.com>here!</a> More info can be found <a href=www.customerservice.com/moreinfo>here!</a>"
```

i.e.

```
{link}{url}{text}{link} --> <a href=url>text</a>
```

Anyone have a good suggestion? I can also change the way the input string is formatted.

Comment: try to use some template engine, here are few: http://stackoverflow.com/a/340243/351383

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following to match:

```
{link}{([^}]*)}{([^}]*)}{link}
```

And replace with:

```
<a href=$1>$2</a>
```

See [DEMO](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%7Blink%7D%7B(%5B%5E%7D%5D*)%7D%7B(%5B%5E%7D%5D*)%7D%7Blink%7D&i=%22Customer%20office%20is%20responsible%20for%20this.%20Contact%20info%20can%20be%20found%20%7Blink%7D%7Bwww.customerservice.com%7D%7Bher!%7D%7Blink%7D%20More%20info%20can%20be%20found%20%7Blink%7D%7Bwww.customerservice.com%2Fmoreinfo%7D%7Bher!%7D%7Blink%7D%22&r=%3Ca%20href%3D%241%3E%242%3C%2Fa%3E)

Explanation:

- `{link}` match `{link}` literally
- `{([^}]*)}` match all characters except `}` in capturing group 1 (for url)
- `{([^}]*)}` match all characters except `}` in capturing group 2 (for value)
- `{link}` match `{link}` literally again

Answer (score 0):

you can use regex as

```
{link}{(.*?)}{(.*?)}{link}
```

and substution as

```
<a href=\1>\2</a>
```

[Regex](https://regex101.com/r/jG0eV4/1)

Answer (score 0):

For your simple link format `{link}{url}{text}` you can use simple `Regex.Replace`:

```
Regex.Replace(input, @"\{link\}\{([^}]*)\}\{([^}]*)\}", @"<a href=""$1"">$2</a>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Also this non-regex idea may help

```
var input = "Customer office is responsible for this. Contact info can be found {link}{www.customerservice.com}{here!}{link} More info can be found {link}{www.customerservice.com/moreinfo}{here!}{link}";

var output = input.Replace("{link}{", "<a href=")
                  .Replace("}{link}", "</a>")
                  .Replace("}{", ">");
```